# Umbraco Extending Tags

Tags: umbraco, extending

I am new to Umbraco CMS, so this question may sound silly. The requirement is to show the tags (based on a specific tag group) to editors in a dropbox, and they could able to choose these tags and save it to the article. What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The tag property allows free text entry. If you only want editors to select from a predefined list of options you will probably need to do this a different way. You may want to try the dropdown property with the multiple choice option turned on instead. Then you can setup the prevalues (options) ahead of time and your editors can only select from that list.

You could also create a container in the tree for your categories and then allow your admins to select the appropriate items from that list using a multinode tree picker. Here's kind of an example of how you might structure this for a blog:

```
Blog
    Authors
        Author
    Categories
        Category
    Posts
        Post
```

Then when an admin adds a new post you would allow them to select the appropriate authors/categories for the post using a multinode tree picker.

Comment: hi Tim ..thanks for the replay.. but in this solution, I will miss the ability for retrieving articles by Tags isn't!! I am using Umbraco content API.

Comment: Dropdown prevalues are saved as a CSV string which means you can still retrieve articles by the datatype using ContentService. You simply need to only select the articles which tag CSV string contains the tag you're looking to retrieve articles for. Another solution is to create nodes for each tag you allow editors to use and then have them pick those using the Multinode Treepicker :)